# Office.js Powerpoint get objects on slide

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, office-js

I am to write a small productivity tool for officejs/powerpoint.

How does one iterate trough the objects on the slide  potentially move them via JS ?

Docs are pretty limited for powerpoint.